# Postgres-XL Standby Server

Tags: database, postgresql, postgres-xl

hello everyone I create a cluster in postgres-XL but I use the command pg_ctl promote but I need a standby server how I can create it I need the cluster to be high availability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this.   Postgres-XL does not support HA or any fail over protection. If you lose a single node the entire database is lost.

The best option they provide is to have a mirror instance of each node, but even  with this if a node fails you will still have to manually take the database down and removed the failed node and replace it with its mirror.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you help me a lot